# getting error for module that doesn't exist in Package.json in react native?

Tags: react-native, node-modules, npm-install, modulenotfounderror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeX5K.jpg)

I am getting error for module that doesn't even exist in Package.json file. what is that and how to resolve this problem

usually i try deleting node modules and then npm install but this time i did it and got this error again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this library then you have to install it using

**npm i @twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input**

Now as u said : " **module that doesn't even exist in Package.json file**" and you are still importing the library e.g

**"import OTPInputView from '@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input'"**

thats why it's giving the error.

just remove this line "import OTPInputView from '@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input'"

Secondly You don't need to delete node modules every time. It should be done only in swear cases.

you can simple try **npm start --Reset-cache**

if you have any other confusion ,feel free to ask

Comment: Yes i also realized my mistake. but i want to use this Library but it throws me errors. should i install older version of react native?

Comment: can u see if it's present in packages.json

Comment: Yes I see it is present but after closing code editor and running again this error went away

Comment: Yes I see it is present but after closing code editor and running again this error went away

Comment: it was a cache issue. you reseted the cache and it's gone. sometime it needs the editor to be closed. pls ranck my answer if you felt it helped u. thanks

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I will definitely rank your answer but I need 15 rep to do that. You rank my question then I rank your answer

Answer (score 1):

"npm install" only installs packages mentioned under package.json file.

As you are getting an error for the module which is not present under package.json, you are supposed to add that module name in package.json file as other modules are mentioned under "dependencies" object.
And after adding the module name you can try "npm install".

Or

You can simply try npm install for that respective package separately, it'll automatically add that module name in package.json and will install the same for you.

for example:
let's suppose you are getting an error for a package called as 'example'

> npm install example